# Algebraic Expressions - Kotlin way to model attributes that are both static and dynamic

Tags: generics, kotlin, dynamic, static, expression

Apologies for the lengthy introduction, I unfortunately can't think of a way to make it any shorter.

#### Problem

We're building a simple app that manipulates algebraic expressions by applying pattern transformations - the goal is to be able to say "Take `2*x+2` and apply 'factoring out'". The eventual goal is to be able to determine if two expressions are equivalent under a set of pattern transformations (i.e. is `2*(x+1)^2` 'reachable' from `2x^2+4x+2`).

We've created a set of classes that model the domain and defined a "canonical" form, which basically means there is exactly one way the (symbolically) same expression will be constructed: `x+y+z` will always be represented as `Plus(x, y, z`) and never as `Plus(y, x, z)` or `Plus(x, Plus(y, z))`, even if it is created by calling `Plus(Plus(x, z), y)`.

Many of these canonical transformations are a direct result of algebraic properties of the corresponding operators - associativity allows for the "flattening" seen above etc. These properties also have a direct effect on the pattern operations - for example, `Power(\_, 2)` is not commutative, so it only matches expressions having `2` as the second child (parameter), but `Plus(_, 2)` is commutative, so it can match an expression having `2` as any of it's children. For these reasons, we wish to represent these algebraic properties as explicit data on the classes, which are then parsed in the respective parts of the app.

The tricky part is that we need this data to be available both statically (we need it when constructing expressions to apply appropriate canonical transformations, but since the expression has yet to be constructed, we can't access it dynamically) and dynamically (during pattern matching, we must be able to do `expr.hasAttribute(Associative)`). Since these attributes are fixed for a specific expression type (class), we're also trying to avoid defining it directly on the class, e.g.

```
class Plus(children: List<Expression>): Expression(children) {
    val attributes = setOf(Associative, Commutative, IdentityElement(Number(0.0)))
    ...
}
```

This is because we don't wan't a new `Set` to be created every time we create an expression - we want the `Set` to be created once, during the class declaration, because that's the only time it needs to be created.

#### Solution

The way we decided to solve this is to create a global `HashMap<KClass<out Expr>, Set<Attribute>>` which will hold the attributes, and then create a Builder object which is responsible for parsing the attributes and applying appropriate canonical transformations when Expressions are created.

I'm including a simplified version of the code we're using. Some high level comments:

- The `HashMap` is defined on `Expression.Companion`
- All expression constructors are protected, and instances are instead created through the `invoke` function defined on the `companion object`. This is because canonical transformations can result in a different object than is being created, for example `Plus(Symbol(x))` creates `Symbol(x)`.
- The builder basically constructs a list of operators (functions) that will then be applied to the children of the expression being constructed - flattening and sorting in this case.

My question is twofold:

1. Is this the way you would approach this? We tried out a couple of other approaches, but all of them required hideous code duplication (and actually turned out to be slower).
2. Can you give me any code review tips on how to make this cleaner? I'm fairly new to Kotlin. As you can see, I ended up creating sort of semi-builder semantics to work with the `Attributes` in the `Builder`. That actually wasn't my goal, it just resulted from trying to make the code cleaner. And I'm sure more could be done.

Thank you!

```
import kotlin.reflect.KClass

/**
 * ATTRIBUTES
 */
abstract class Attribute
object Associative: Attribute()
object Commutative: Attribute()
class Identity(val element: Expr) : Attribute()
/**
 * END ATTRIBUTES
 */


/**
 * BUILDER
 */
// So there are basically two things we can do in canonical form -> we can operate on children (flattening, canonical ordering)
// or we can operate on the final expression as a whole (transforming Plus(x) to x, for example)
// So, every attribute may or may not contribute a functional operator that transforms either the children or the expression
// as a whole. These operators must be composed in a certain order (e.g. flattening must occur before ordering) and then
// applied to the result.
// The operators that change the expressions type short-circuit the function (because there is nothing else to do)
object Builder {

    inline fun<reified A: Attribute> Set<Attribute>.withAttribute(block: A.() -> Any?) =
            this.filterIsInstance<A>().firstOrNull()?.run(block)

    inline fun<reified E: Expr> withAttributes(block: Set<Attribute>.() -> Any?)
            = Expr.attributes[E::class]?.run(block)

    inline fun<reified E: Expr> canonizeByAttributes(crossinline constructor: (List<Expr>) -> E, children: List<Expr>): Expr {

        val childrenOperators = mutableListOf<(List<Expr>) -> List<Expr>>()

        withAttributes<E> {
            withAttribute<Identity> {
                when(children.size) {
                    0 -> return element
                    1 -> return children.first()
                    else -> {}
                }
            }

            withAttribute<Associative> {
                childrenOperators.add {
                    children -> children.flatMap { if(it is E) it.children else listOf(it) }
                }
            }

            withAttribute<Commutative> {
                childrenOperators.add {
                    children -> children.sortedBy { it.toString() }
                }
            }
        }

        return constructor(childrenOperators.fold(children) { children, op -> op(children)})
    }
}
/**
 * END BUILDER
 */


/**
 * EXPRESSIONS
 */
abstract class Expr protected constructor(val children: List<Expr>) {
    val attributes: Set<Attribute>? get() = Companion.attributes[this::class]

    override fun toString(): String = "${this::class.simpleName}(${children.joinToString(", ")})"

    companion object {
        val attributes: HashMap<KClass<out Expr>, Set<Attribute>> = hashMapOf()
    }
}

Expr.attributes[Plus::class] = setOf(Identity(Symbol("0")), Commutative, Associative)
class Plus private constructor(children: List<Expr>): Expr(children) {

    companion object {
        operator fun invoke(children: List<Expr>) = Builder.canonizeByAttributes(::Plus, children)
        operator fun invoke(vararg children: Expr) = invoke(children.toList())
    }

}

class Symbol(val name: String): Expr(listOf()) {
    override fun toString(): String = "Symbol($name)"
}
/**
 * END EXPRESSIONS
 */


/**
 * EVALUATION, TESTS
 */
Plus(Symbol("x")).attributes

(Plus(Symbol("x")) as Symbol).name == "x"

(Plus(Symbol("x"), Plus(Symbol("x"), Symbol("y"))))

(Plus() as Symbol).name == "0"

(Plus(Plus()) as Symbol).name == "0"

Plus(Symbol("2"), Symbol("y"), Plus(Symbol("x"), Symbol("1")))
/**
 * END EVALUATION, TESTS
 */
```

Answer (score 1):

You can have a set property without creating a new instance each time, e.g.:

```
private val plusAttributes = setOf(Associative, Commutative, IdentityElement(Number(0.0)))

class Plus(children: List<Expression>): Expression(children) {
    val attributes = plusAttributes
    // ...
}
```

That way all instances of Plus have a reference to the same set.  There's still the overhead of an extra reference in each instance, but far less than for a set (which can have a large object tree).

Even better, make `attributes` an abstract property up in the `Expression` class, overridden in each implementing class.  That way, you can access the attributes without knowing which type of expression.

Another approach you might consider is using marker interfaces that the relevant subclasses implement in addition to extending Expression.  That has no overhead at all, and is very easy and clear to test: `if (myExpression is Associative)`, though it doesn't give you a map of them all in one go.  (And if there's any behaviour associated with the attribute, you can add a method to the relevant interface, which is heading toward more traditional OO design.)

Comment: Thanks for the tips, however in both of them I'm unclear how I would achieve static access, i.e. in Builder - there is no instance at that point, so I cannot access them. There are 2 solutions I can think of: create a "dummy" expression to allow dynamic access, which just seems wrong and also defeats the guarantee of "every expression is always in canonical form" or 2) have "attributes" both on the class and on the Companion object. This is the "hideous code duplication" I was referencing earlier, disregarding the fact that Companion objects don't inherit

Comment: @GabrielShanahan Ah, I see now what you meant by ‘both statically and dynamically’…  Perhaps it wouldn't involve too much duplication if, in my example code, you moved `plusAttributes` into the companion object, and renamed it to `attributes`?  Then you could access it ‘statically’.  (And note that in Kotlin, the companion object _can_ extend another class and/or implement interfaces.  So you needed to access it in a polymorphic way, it could implement some common interface.)  But I'm afraid I'm probably missing too much of the bigger picture to be much help.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand what you mean, but even if I make the companion objects extend a common interface, I still have no way of guaranteeing to the compiler that a companion object exists on classes deriving Expression. Every subclass (Plus, Times, Symbol, Pow) would have to define it's own companion, but even if it extended a common interface, the compiler wouldn't allow me to access it without explicitly specifying the type: ie. Plus.attributes works, but <T: Expr> T::attributes doesn't, which prevents me from abstracting the code. The only solution to that is reflection.

Comment: @GabrielShanahan I think there _is_ a way that doesn't need reflection.  If all the companions implement a `HasAttributes` interface with a property called `attributes`, then you can do it with just a cast: `(T::class.companionObjectInstance as HasAttributes).attributes`.  (It's still ugly, and it's a shame you can't avoid the cast by specifying a restriction in the superclass, of course, but maybe this is better than nothing?)

Comment: Also, thank you for the discussion, it helps knowing that I'm thinking about this along the same lines as someone else. Looking at the code I posted, do you see any possible improvements to what I'm doing in this specific way? For instance, I'd really like to solve the ugly issue of having returns all over the place in canonizeByAttributes, but the only thing I can think of is converting the return statements to lambdas which would then get executed at the end instead of the call to constructor() (basically something similar to what I do with childrenOperators). What do you think?

Comment: Sorry, missed your latest comment. This is one of the approaches we tried, but finally decided against it, just because it seemed wrong to create interfaces/classes just to solve an implementation issue. But it does work, and it's also about 30% faster than the solution I posted, it's just pretty ugly as you say :)